# Removing an element JS vs CSS for Page speed

Tags: javascript, css, performance

Is there any difference in page speed if you remove elements from displaying with javascript instead of CSS?

If for example I had a lot of content in the sidebar, but wanted to remove it for smaller screens, I would do:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1025px) {

    .sidebar { 
        display: none; 
    }
}
```

I'm not used to using js, but I found out how to do the same thing with jquery:

```
var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;

if(width < 1025) {

     $(".sidebar").remove();
}
```

Is there any difference in terms of speed between the two?

Comment: What if you resize the window?

Comment: The codes you have provided is not a same things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS will always outperform JS, but there are many things you can do in JS that you cannot in CSS.

Note that your JS example will work only once (unless you add an onresize listener) while the CSS example will always respond to changes.

Next, your JS example removes the element from the DOM, while the CSS only hides it by setting the display property to none (but the element is still present in the DOM and can be restored, unlike the JS example).

The equal JS code would be:

```
$(window).on('resize', handleWidth);

function handleWidth(){
  var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
  if(width < 1025)
     $(".sidebar").hide(); // document.getElementById('sidebar').style.display = 'none';
  else 
     $(".sidebar").show(); // document.getElementById('sidebar').style.display = 'block';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS is best. All content will be loaded either way. Then you have JS happening after!

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provided, the css is hiding the element and the jquery is being deleted.

In vanilla js to hide an element you do this:
`document.getElementById("El").style.display = none`

The difference between that and css is so minimal it would never make a difference in speed.